# Data Aggregation with Java and MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am currently programming with Java and the MongoDB driver, but I'm stuck at using the `Aggregate.group()` method, like it's mentioned in the official API: https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.3/

After some time of trial and error I achieved a working version of the group functionality, but by using mongodb expressions instead of the java method. I want to calculate the average income of males and females with the group command and sort the results after that. Can anybody give me an example how to code it right with the `Aggregates.group()` command instead of using the `$group` command?

```
collection.aggregate(asList(new Document("$group",
                new Document("_id", "$gender").append("avg", new Document("$avg", "$income"))
```

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/40307659/get-average-from-mongo-collection-using-aggrerate. can be marked as duplicate.

Comment: Post your sample document and expected output